# Trying to use a grails domain class from the shell

Tags: hibernate, spring, shell, grails, groovy

I'm new to Grails.

I'm trying to experiement with my grails domains from the shell, and I can't get it to work. These domains work fine from the scaffold code when I run the app.

Given this domain class

```
class IncomingCall {

    String caller_id
    Date call_time
    int  call_length

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I try to create an "IncomingCall" and save it from the shell. No matter what I do, I always get "Null"; the object isn't created.

And if I try to create the object and then do a save, I get the "No hibernate session bound to thread" error (see below).

```
groovy:000> new IncomingCall(caller_id:'555-1212', call_time: new Date(), call_length:10).save()
ERROR org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession (SpringSessionContext.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession (SessionFactoryImpl.java:574)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:3)
    ...
groovy:000>
```

How can I make this work from the shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this highly annoying problem as well.

To fix it, run this code in the shell to bind the hibernate session to the transaction synchronization manager:

```
import org.hibernate.Session
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager
sessionFactory = ctx.getBean("sessionFactory")
session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, true)
TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, new SessionHolder(session))
```

After that's done, domain objects should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using Grails domain classes from the shell usually doesn't work well. One thing i notices is that you don't have any import statements. If your classes are in package com.my.domain before trying to create and instance of the class you need to do

```
import com.my.domain.*
```